# Creating a Java 7, Tomcat 7 Elastic Beanstalk instance using CLI/Boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to write a Boto script (Python lib for AWS) that creates an Elastic beanstalk environment using Java 7 and Tomcat 7. I can find the possible options that a configuration template allows me to provide using:

```
beanstalk.describe_configuration_options("app_name", "existing_template")
```

However, this does not list anything like the Java version or the Tomcat version. How do I specify that I want a Java 7, Tomcat 7 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of available solution stacks for a particular region with the following code:

```
from boto import beanstalk

conn = beanstalk.connect_to_region(region_name='us-west-1')

response = conn.list_available_solution_stacks()

available_solution_stacks = response['ListAvailableSolutionStacksResponse']['ListAvailableSolutionStacksResult']['SolutionStacks']
```

To create new environment you should use `create_environment` method:

```
from boto import beanstalk

conn = beanstalk.connect_to_region(region_name='us-west-1')

conn.create_application(application_name='angry-whopper-jr')

conn.create_environment(
    application_name='angry-whopper-jr',
    environment_name='development',
    solution_stack_name='64bit Amazon Linux 2013.09 running Tomcat 7 Java 7'
)
```

Full description of boto.beanstalk API is available here: [Elastic Beanstalk](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/beanstalk.html)

Comment: Sheesh, how could I have missed that? I looked the docs over 5 times! Great stuff, thanks!